# Next.js Flask Deployment - Flask doesnt run on vercel

Tags: flask, vercel

I did an app which runs normally on localhost, but when I deploy the app to vercel, I get 404 error code for server page and I get 405 for sending data to server.

I have my python in pages/api

I changed my package.json like this:

`"scripts": { "flask-dev": "python -m flask --app pages/api/index run -p 8080 --reload", "next-dev": "next dev", "dev": "concurrently \"pnpm run next-dev\" \"pnpm run flask-dev\"" },`

Localy I type "npm run dev" and both servers run.

Since the vercel runs "next build" to run the app, how can I make it run the server as well?